# Not able to connect with ElasticSearch 7.3.0 for logger dependency error in elasticSearch client

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, java, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm running a simple method that will connect with elasticsearch and feed data to a particular index with the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/transport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Following is the code block that I have run

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;

public class Es {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.builder().put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                    .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", true).build())
                            .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
            String json = "{" + "\"user\":\"kimchy\"," + "\"postDate\":\"2013-01-30\","
                    + "\"message\":\"trying out Elasticsearch\"" + "}";
            IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "_doc").setSource(json, XContentType.JSON).get();
            // Index name
            System.out.println(response.getIndex());
            // Type name
            System.out.println(response.getType());
            // Document ID (generated or not)
            System.out.println(response.getId());
            // Version (if it's the first time you index this document, you will get: 1)
            System.out.println(response.getVersion());
            // status has stored current instance statement.
            System.out.println(response.status());
            client.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When i run the main method it will show the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(java.lang.String)'
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4InternalESLogger.<init>(Netty4InternalESLogger.java:34)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils$1.newInstance(Netty4Utils.java:53)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.getInstance(InternalLoggerFactory.java:93)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.getInstance(InternalLoggerFactory.java:86)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:70)
    at io.netty.util.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:32)
    at io.netty.util.AttributeKey$1.<init>(AttributeKey.java:27)
    at io.netty.util.AttributeKey.<clinit>(AttributeKey.java:27)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.<clinit>(Netty4Transport.java:231)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin.getSettings(Netty4Plugin.java:56)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.lambda$getPluginSettings$0(PluginsService.java:89)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.getPluginSettings(PluginsService.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:156)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:296)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:130)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:116)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:106)
    at com.example.demo.Es.main(Es.java:20)
```

I am also changing the ElasticSearch client dependency version to 6.9 to 7.3 but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the logger dependency to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of using log4j-to-slf4j, slf4j-api & logback-classic